# Increasing compression ratio UglifyJS - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs

Currently I am able to minify using UglifyJS in the node environment. However, after reading this [blog](https://davidwalsh.name/compress-uglify), I realise there are more options to this plugin. But I'm not able to translate those keywords into a syntax acceptable for the node environment.

Right now, `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})` is what I am using to minify the build file generated by webpack.

So, few questions.

1. Does `minimize:true` toggle all the optional states to `true` as well?
2. If it doesn't, how are we supposed to mention it as an argument?
3. If we are to find those options manually, where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the `minimize` option in any documentation so I'm not sure what it actually does, but to set the additional options for compression, you can use this:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress : {
    dead_code     : true,
    drop_debugger : true,
    conditionals  : true,
    ...
  }
})
```